# Thread-safe, lock-free increment function?

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, lock-free

**UPDATED:** Is there a thread-safe, lock-free and available on all Linux distros *increment* function available in C or C++ ?

Comment: This will be a part of C++0x when that comes out.

Comment: You say "lock-free", and the alternatives specified below are lock-free.

But they are not cost-free; atomic operations require coordination of all cores on a processor, which includes flushing the cache.

So if you find your multi-threaded program incrementing this counter thousands of times per second, the atomic operations will have a noticeable effect on your performance.

Comment: @Martin: "there is nothing free in this universe" that's what I always say :-)  Thanks for you comment: the frequency at which I'll be using this facility is very low.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GLib has functions to do this. You might check out http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Atomic-Operations.html

Specifically, it sounds like you want g_atomic_int_inc()

Comment: Would I need to include GLib as a dependency to my project? Or is this just a .lib ?

Comment: Yes, you would need to link to glib, but that shouldn't be a problem since it is available by default on every(?) Linux distro out there.

Comment: It's only available on systems with GNOME installed.

Comment: While technically GLib is used in GTK+ programs, and typically GTK+ programs run on GNOME, most Linux distributions I'd expect would have a copy of GLib as GTK+ programs are just so prevalent on Linux. Failing which, it's easy enough to download via the distro's package manager

Answer (score 10):

### 2021 answer

#### C++

12 years have passed since the other answers and it is now in the standard and it is possible to do this since C++11 using the [atomic operations library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

int main() {
    std::atomic<int> atomic_i{5};
    std::cout << atomic_i.is_lock_free() << std::endl; // 1, which means lock free
    atomic_i++;
    std::cout << atomic_i << std::endl; // 6
    return 0;
}
```

If interested, this compiles into (with at least -O1 optimisation on gcc):

```
mov             DWORD PTR [rsp-4], 5
lock inc        DWORD PTR [rsp-4]
```

If you want a normal, non-atomic integer that you want to increment in atomic operations only some of the time, you can use [`atomic_ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref) since C++20, if you ensure it's sufficiently aligned.  (Some systems under-align some non-atomic types for historical ABI reasons but require natural alignment for atomics to actually work efficiently / correctly. Notably 32-bit x86 with `int64_t` and `double` where `alignof(T) < std::atomic_ref<T>::required_alignment`).

Note that *"While any atomic_ref instances referencing an object exists, the object must be exclusively accessed through these atomic_ref instances."*
See [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:combine_bytes.c,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:19,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:19,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:19,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:19),source:%27%23include+%3Catomic%3E%0A%0A//+This+alignment+is+redundant+for+int+on+most+mainstream+implementations%0A//+but+is+important+for+portability+or+for+wider+types+like+int64_t%0Aalignas(std::atomic_ref%3Cint%3E::required_alignment)++int+j+%3D+8%3B%0A%0Avoid+foo()%0A%7B%0A++++//+...+pass+the+address+of+j+to+other+threads%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++std::atomic_ref%3Cint%3E+refj(j)%3B%0A++++++++refj%2B%2B%3B+//+atomic+operation,+j+is+now+9%0A++++%7D%0A++++//+refj+goes+out+of+scope,+so+it!%27s+ok+to+use+j+again%0A++++%0A++++//+...++//+some+synchronization+so+we+know+other+threads+are+done+for+now%0A++++j%2B%2B%3B+//+non-atomic+increment,+j+is+now+10%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:combine_bytes.c,t:%270%27)),k:51.9774011299435,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g112,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Og+-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:48.0225988700565,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) how it compiles.

```cpp
// This alignment is redundant for int on most mainstream implementations
// but is important for portability or for wider types like int64_t
alignas(std::atomic_ref<int>::required_alignment)  int j = 8;

... // pass the address of j to other threads
{
    std::atomic_ref<int> refj(j);
    refj++; // atomic operation, j is now 9
}
// refj goes out of scope, so it's ok to use j again

 ... // some synchronization so we know other threads are done for now
j++; // non-atomic increment, j is now 10
```

---

#### C

You can do the same as in my first example in C11 too, using [atomic types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic).

```
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    atomic_int i = 5;
    i++; // atomic operation
    printf("%d\n", i); // 6
    return 0;
}
```

There isn't a C equivalent for C++20 `std::atomic_ref`.  If you don't mind using GNU extensions, you can use the builtin functions that C++ `atomic` and `atomic_ref` are implemented on top of, like [GNU C `__atomic` builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html): `__atomic_fetch_add( &i, 1, __ATOMIC_ACQ_REL)`.

Other compilers for non-Linux systems have their own builtins, for example [MSVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/interlocked-variable-access) with `_InterlockedAdd`.

It may happen to work to point an `atomic_int *` (aka `_Atomic int*`) at the address of an `int`, but this is strict-aliasing undefined behaviour.

Comment: How about adding C11 `_Atomic`, too?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Good point, I added a C example as well.

Answer (score 6):

I think these are GNU extensions, and processor specific, but have a look at [GNU C Atomic Builtins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html).

I think there are also atomic "libraries" available that use inline assembly etc. to provide such features.

Answer (score 4):

The current C and C++ standards don't define such a thing.  Your implementation may well have one.

Comment: This is no longer the case since C11 and C++11, see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70084063/898783